# Missing "md-accent" css class in Angular material-design css file

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design

In Material AngularJS doc (https://material.angularjs.org/#/Theming/02_declarative_syntax) tells that the "md-accent" can be used, along with "md-primary" and "md-warn":

> The classes to apply the color intention for a given component are as follows: md-primary, md-accent, md-warn.

```
<md-button class="md-primary">Click me</md-button>
<md-button class="md-accent">or maybe me</md-button>
<md-button class="md-warn">Careful</md-button>
```

However, the class "md-accent" doesn't appear in official css file: 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.css

I saw an example in: https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.button

```
<md-button class="md-accent">Accent</md-button>
<md-button class="md-accent md-raised md-hue-3">Accent Hue 3</md-button>
```

But It doesn't work for me, I've tested it on different components and "md-accent" does nothing.

Is the doc obsolete ? Am I missing something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in 0.6.1, the docs are using (in the moment I wrote this) the version 0.7.0-rc1.

If I use the "snapshot" version (v0.7.0-rc2), It works fine:

```
<!-- Angulars Material CSS using RawGit to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">

<!-- Angular Material Javascript using RawGit to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
<script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
```